# How to properly create a DLL from C code and use it in a C++ project

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have a set of functions written in C that I need to be able to call from another project written in C++. The C code is essentially some functions that do some calculations on a large data set. I didn't write them - all I want to do is allow my C++ project to be able to call those functions. My solution was to create a DLL for the C code and link it to my C++ project.

In order to make the DLL, I structured myCproj.h (the header in the **C project**, not C++ project) like so:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct __declspec(dllexport) neededStruct {
    int a;
    //I need to be able to initialize this struct in my C++ project.
}

__declspec(dllexport) void neededFunc( struct neededStruct *input ) {}
    //I need to be able to call this function from my C++ project and feed 
    //it my local instance of neededStruct.

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The src file, myCproj.c, was not changed at all. The function definitions do not have `__declspec(dllexport)`in front of them, nor is `extern "C"` inserted anywhere. The code compiles without error and produces myCproj.dll and myCproj.lib.

I then tell my C++ project in VS where to find myCproj.lib and myCproj.h accordingly and copy the DLL over to the directory where my C++ executable lives. To use the DLL, I gave myCPPproj.cpp the following addition:

```
#define DLLImport __declspec(dllimport)

struct DLLImport neededStruct input;
input.a = 0;

extern "C" DLLImport void neededFunc( &input );
```

However, I get error EO335 'linkage specification is not allowed' on that last line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `myCproj.h` uses `__declspec(dllexport)`. This is only correct when you **build** your library. This is incorrect when you **use** it. You need to conditionally define the `__declspec` attribute to either dllimport or dllexport depending on what you are building.

Comment: @n.m but I am building my library...that is the header file for the C project not the C++ project.

Comment: This is a little confusing. In your question, you say, "I then tell my C++ project in VS where to find `myCproj.lib` and `myCproj.h`" which implies you were including `myCproj.h` in your C++ app. But you're saying that you are not doing that? And it does appear, from the code you show, that you are indeed using `__declspec(dllexport)` in your `extern` statement in C++. That's not the case either?

Comment: By the way, it would make more sense to write a DLL function to initialize the struct, rather than accessing it directly from your C++ app.

Comment: @lurker so I thought in order to use a DLL it is preferable to have the actual header used to make that DLL and that to access the library you need to include that header in your project. That's called implicit linking right? My understanding is that linking only the DLL would be explicitly linking it, but since I have both the .lib and the .h file, I might as well implicitly link it.

Comment: It's good to have a header file for defining the external function, but the declaration in the header file is for an "export" not an "import", at least as you are showing it. Your C++ shows it declared as "import" but then you'd have two different definitions in your C++ file if you are, indeed, including the header as well as shown.

Comment: OH I see what you mean. But it is defined as an export because it's used in compiling the DLL itself. Isn't it supposed to tell the C compiler that such and such function is intended to be exported? If I chage the header to say "import" instead, then no where in the entire C project will it tell the compiler that those functions are to be exported.

Comment: You wouldn't want the calling C++ file to have it declared as both an import and an export. Should just be import.

Comment: The normal accepted way is to use the same header for both projects. Why do you need `#ifdef __cplusplus` in a header which is *noit* used in a C++ project?

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to use the same header for both the library and using code.
As mentioned, it is usually done by a conditional define, like the following:
MyLibrary.h:

```
#if defined(MYLIBRARY_API)
#define MYLIBRARY_EXPORTS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIBRARY_EXPORTS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

MYLIBRARY_API bool MyLibFunc();

#if defined(__cplusplus)
#endif
```

MyLibrary.c:

```
#include "MyLibrary.h"

void MyLibFunc()
{
....
}
```

App.cpp:

```
#include <MyLibrary.h>

int main()
{
MyLibFunc();
}
```

The symbol MYLIBRARY_API will be defined for the library project (usually as a /D on the compiler command line). And if you use visual studio that is pretty much exactly what you get when creating a dll project with exports.

Comment: Where/how is `MYLIBRARY_API` defined? Also, from a naming standpoint, it's a little odd to have `MYLIBRARY_EXPORT` defined in some cases as `__declspec(dllimport)`. I'd probably find a different suitable name.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! But what is the naming convention for the symbol "MYLIBRARY_API"? Does it have to be the name of the header in all caps with "_API" appended? I've seen other people use "_EXPORTS" as the suffix too.